# How to make iterable class method?

Tags: javascript, iterable

It's telling me "TypeError: Foo.my_method(...) is not a function or its return value is not async iterable". How to make it so?

```js
class Foo {
  constructor() {
        return (async () => { this.sleep(1000) })()
  }
  
  async *my_method(message) {
    let pos = 0
    while (true) {
      yield message.charAt(pos)
      await this.sleep(100)
      pos += 1
    }
  }
  
  sleep(ms) {
        return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
    }
}

let foo = new Foo().then(async () => {
    for await (let msg of foo.my_method("AAAA")) {
        msgs.push(msg)
    }
})
```

Comment: Provide an actual [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or more complete code for concrete help. But in theory this works fine. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fsr1qL7e/)

Comment: Just fix the stuff which you've typed as `...`. If that explanation isn't sufficient, then don't use `...` but a [mcve].

Comment: Now it's reproducible

Comment: `constructor() { return (async () => { this.sleep(1000) })() }` was ***SUPER IMPORTANT!*** Your initial code was similar to going to the car mechanic and saying "My car seems to have trouble starting." And you don't show the car, just talk him through what you tried. Charging the battery, changing the oil, running diagnostics checks. But omitting the fact that it wasn't a car but it was a block of cheese you were trying this with. Which doesn't really run like a car does. Or at all. Because you've *overridden* the constructor to return *something which is not your class instance*.

Comment: yeah, sorry, i was so silly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing

```
let foo = new Foo().then(
```

will set foo to be a Promise, which is why you couldn't do `foo.my_method()`

I think what you are trying to do is this:

```js
class Foo {
  load(){
    return Promise.resolve()
  }
  
  async *my_method(message) {
    let pos = 0
    while (pos < message.length) {
      yield await this.sleep(100).then(() => message.charAt(pos))
      pos += 1
    }
  }
  
  sleep(ms) {
        return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
    }
}

(async function(){
  let foo = new Foo()
  await foo.load()
  
  const msg = []
  for await (const data of foo.my_method("ABCD")) {
      msg.push(data)
  }
  console.log(msg)
})()
```

I have just added a condition on the `while` so that your generator terminates at some point, and I put the async loop into an (async) IFEE, so that the generator can be awaited directly (it looks like this is what you were trying to do).

Does that work for you? Let me know if it make sense.

Comment: I need to wait until constructor finish its work, it takes a while, seems like it's my actual question

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to write a constructor that needs to be awaited. If you need to wait for data before you can instantiate the object, do that, i.e. `fetch().then(data => new Foo(data))`. This will give you more flexibility and does not couple your class to the way you retrieve it's data.

Comment: Okay, thank you, I moved all the long-running stuff to an another initialization method and it's working now.

Comment: @rigiva "*I need to wait until constructor finish its work, it takes a while, seems like it's my actual question*" Yeah, it's called [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 0):

returning  async function from the constructor is not ok. in pure js it would do something (not useful at all in the example from the question), but ts just won't allow that to happen without puting `any` fo the type.

I think you are implementing some kind of collection and this is the way to make async iterable collection

```
class Foo {
  constructor(private message: string) {}
  async *[Symbol.asyncIterator]() {
    let pos = 0
    while (this.message[pos]) {
      yield this.message.charAt(pos)
      await this.sleep(100)
      pos += 1
    }
  }
  
  sleep(ms: number) {
        return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
    }
}

async function userCode() {
    let foo = new Foo('xxx');
    const msgs = [];
    for await (let msg of foo) {
        msgs.push(msg)
    }
    console.log(msgs);
}
```

by declaring `Symbol.asyncIterator` on the class, all instances would be async iterable

Answer (score -2):

this.my_method = async funtion(){...}

Try like this

Comment: Now it yells at my yield with "SyntaxError: Unexpected strict mode reserved word"

Comment: Asynchronous functions aren't iterable.